# Migrating TrueCrypt protected Windows XP installation to new hard disk

Tags: windows-xp, truecrypt, clone

I have Windows XP Prof installed on a Truecrypt protected parition (using TrueCrypt boot authentication). This is the only partition on that drive.

I'm about to get a new harddrive and need to migrate my Windows XP installation to the new drive. To make things even more tricky, the new drive (120GB) is smaller than the old drive (and partition, 160GB), but big enough to easily hold the used parts of the old partition.

Ideally, this is done with as little fuss as possible, ie cloning and shrinking the partition and boot info with some tool, but I'm open to solutions which involve "Re-install Windows on the new drive then use software XXX to migrate all installed drivers / programs / data to the new installation" if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest route is to decrypt the old drive and migrate it using conventional tools (your favorite imaging tools), then encrypt the new drive.  Of course you would have to make a new recovery disk for truecrypt.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If true crypt will allow, use an imaging program to make a disk image and "ghost"  it.